# Using on('click') event with jQuery and changeclass only fires once

Tags: jquery

In the script below, the first click on the "toggleExtras" span works. But subsequent clicks do nothing. I'm trying to use the on('click') method along with a toggleClass to define events for both toggled and untoggled states.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('.toggleExtras').on('click', function(e)
        {
            //jQuery('.extras').slideToggle(); //This works but bounces twice.
            jQuery('.extras').show();
            jQuery('.toggleExtras').text('Hide Advanced Options');
            jQuery('.toggleExtras').toggleClass('toggleExtras toggleExtrasHide');
        });

        jQuery('.toggleExtrasHide').on('click', function(e)
        {
            jQuery('.extras').hide();
            jQuery('.toggleExtrasHide').text('Show Advanced Options');
            jQuery('.toggleExtrasHide').toggleClass('toggleExtrasHide toggleExtras');
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <span class="toggleExtras">Show Advanced Options</span>
```

Comment: Could you post an example with the error on jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm not getting a console error. The clicks on the changed class element do nothing. The class gets changed, but the on('click') does not fire for that element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `.toggleExtrasHide` doesn't exist at the time of initialization...

I'd re-write your code like this:

```
jQuery('.toggleExtras').on('click', function(e){
  jQuery('.extras').toggle();
  jQuery(this).text(function(el, currentValue){
    return currentValue == "Show Advanced Options" ? "Hide Advanced Options" : "Show Advanced Options";
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xbLc2/

Read more about `.toggle()` : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
Read more about `.text()`   : http://api.jquery.com/text/